# what does this asp.net mvc compile time error states?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compilation

I have a repository class and it has this,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CrMVC.BusinessObjects;

namespace CrMVC.Models
{
    public class ConstructionRepository
    {
        private CRDataContext db = new CRDataContext();

        public IQueryable<MaterialsObj> FindAllMaterials()
        {
           var materials =  from m in db.Materials
             join Mt in db.MeasurementTypes on m.MeasurementTypeId equals Mt.Id
                select new MaterialsObj()
                   {
                       Id = Convert.ToInt64(m.Mat_id),
                       Mat_Name = m.Mat_Name,
                       Mes_Name = Mt.Name,
                   };
            return materials;

        }
    }
 }
```

And My MaterialsObj class is under `CrMVC.BusinessObjects` namespace and i using it in my repository class....

```
namespace CrMVC.BusinessObjects
{
    public class MaterialsObj
    {
         //My logic here
    }
}
```

But when i compile this i get this error

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
Files\root\19360d4c\3d21e226\App_Web_materials.aspx.7d2669f4.a8f-zsw5.0.cs(148):
error CS0426: The type name 'Materials' does not exist 
 in the type 'CrMVC.Models.ConstructionRepository'
```

Am i missing something any suggestion....

**Edit:**

There is no class named `Materials` in my repository class then why i get this error..

My view page has this,

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
 Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<CrMVC.Models.ConstructionRepository+Materials>>" %>
```

Comment: The problem is in App_Web_materials.aspx (probably materials.aspx in some App\Web or App_Web directory).  Can you paste the code around line 148 from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the type `CrMVC.Models.ConstructionRepository.Materials` in your ASPX when you probably want to reference `CrMVC.BusinessObjects.MaterialsObj` instead.